# Is Double Tabbar on Bottom Allowed By Apple

Tags: ios, ios5, ios6, uitabbarcontroller

We are working on a layout design for our social media area and wondering if a layout like the following would be rejected by Apple ?  Is a double Tabbar design on the bottom allowed for a use case as shown ?

[image: Double Tab Bar]

Comment: No, this is in direct violation if the [HIG](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/userexperience/conceptual/mobilehig/UIElementGuidelines/UIElementGuidelines.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006556-CH13-SW52): `A tab bar appears at the bottom edge of the screen and should be accessible from every location in the app.` and `Don’t use a tab bar to give users controls that act on elements in the current mode or screen`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Generally - you won't get a definitive answer about what will and will not be approved by Apple. Because it's not something that a definitive answer can be given for. They have guidelines, and apply them as *they* see fit.

However - in this case I would say no. For the following reasons.

1. Tab bars are generally supposed to be used as the root view of an application. If you have one embedded with the other, what is the root view.
2. It takes up a lot of screen space to have two rather than one, it's not like it's a toolbar
3. It's ugly.

Comment: Agree on #3. Plus it's easy to hit the wrong tab bar.

Comment: Thanks everyone... I was fairly certain this was the case.. and not a working use case.  We will stick with a contextual navigation using a toolbar action for the other channel based on what channel you are on.

Answer (score 0):

Apple reserves the right to reject any applications that violate their Human Interface Guidelines (HIG). Stacked `UITabBar`s violate the HIG. That being said, this isn't the place to ask. No one here can tell you what a particular reviewer on a particular day will do.